# Invocation of MavenCli fails within a Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-embedder

I've created small util to wrap `MavenCli`, which generates a new Maven project, using the quickstart archetype.

When executing the `Util` as a unit test, it is working quite well (just generating an empty Maven project).

Now I want to integrate this small wrapper into a Maven plugin. But when I execute the mojo (within a third Maven project), the invocation of `MavenCli` fails with exception:

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.util.NoSuchElementException
  role: org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher
  roleHint: 
[ERROR] Caused by: null
```

The util looks like:

```
public void createProject() {
    final MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
    System.setProperty("maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory", "/usr/share/maven");
    cli.doMain(new String[] { "archetype:generate", "-DgroupId=com.my.company",
            "-DartifactId=hello-world", "-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart",
            "-DinteractiveMode=false" }, "/tmp", System.out, System.out);
}
```

relevant dependency of the util:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

The mojo code looks like:

```
@Mojo(name = "custommojo", requiresProject = false)
public class CustomMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        Util.createProject();
    }

}
```

The POM of the mojo just includes dependencies to relevant Maven artifacts (plugin-api, plugin-annotation, etc.) and the util.

The third project I mentioned, is an empty "maven-quickstart" project which have dependency to the mojo-project and a configuration for the mojo to execute in compile phase.

I have no idea why it works in context of unit test, but not in context of a mojo.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a class loading issue.

`MavenCli` will try to load classes from the context classloader of the current thread. Inside of a Maven plugin, there is [a special, restricted, classloader](https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/maven/content/reference/maven-classloading.html#Plugin_classloaders), which has access to:

- its own classes;
- the classes used in its dependencies block;
- exported classes as part of a possible build extension of the project;
- exported classes from the Maven core and core extensions;
- and has the bootstrap classloader as parent.

However, the specific class `org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher` is part of Maven core, but [it is not part of the exported APIs](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/extension.xml) (the package `org.apache.maven.eventspy` is not listed as an `exportedPackage`). So the plugin cannot load that class. This is also why it works in your tests: you're not inside of a plugin, so the classloader is different and has access to that class.

You won't even be able to get away with adding explictly a dependency on `maven-core` for the plugin: it will be disgarded since it is supposedly already provided.

There are 2 solutions here:

- Don't use the Maven Embedder API from within a plugin, but the [Invoker API](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/). The difference between the two is that the Invoker API will launch Maven in a clean environment, completely distinct with regard to the current one. Since it starts everything anew, you won't have any classloading issue.
- Use the [mojo-executor](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor) library, that provides an easy way to invoke other Mojos from within a Maven plugin. You could use it here to invoke the `archetype:generate` Mojo.

Comment: Thank you a lot - I switched to Invoker API as suggested - and it works pretty well. Note: Before I used Embedder API, I tried already to use mojo-executor, but without success, since it is difficult to execute a whole Lifecycle (e.g. "install") - mojo-executor is working for "archetype:generate", but is also difficult to configure when trying to invoke a mojo for another project (especially when this other project is completely out of scope of the current build)

Comment: It is in fact possible to handle the class loading issue and using `MavenCli`, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me inside a custom maven plugin (using Maven 3.5.0):

```
ClassRealm classRealm = (ClassRealm) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
MavenCli cli = new MavenCli(classRealm.getWorld());
cli.doMain( ... );
```

The plexus Launcher [sets the context class loader](https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-classworlds/blob/4e4ccaae2041b04d8808d1125151343b1ba221e4/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher.java#L287) to its `ClassRealm`, which has access to the "global" `ClassWorld`.

Not sure how stable that solution is, but so far looking good.

Used imports:

```
import org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.ClassWorld;
import org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm;
import org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli;
```

Comment: I got a cast error when trying this but it put me in the right direction:
'
    MavenCli cli = new MavenCli(new ClassWorld("maven",Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()));
'

Comment: same issue with me as well!

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander:

You answer put me in the right direction, I was getting the mentioned error when trying to run to doMain maven commands subsequently (one command would succeed).

However your code gives me a ClassCast exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm
    at com.misys.tools.integration.codegen.cli.cmd.InstallApi.mavenInstallMchApi(InstallApi.java:58)
    at com.misys.tools.integration.codegen.cli.cmd.InstallApi.run(InstallApi.java:50)
    at com.misys.tools.integration.codegen.cli.OpenApiGen.main(OpenApiGen.java:26)
```

I managed to rewrite the code to:

```
MavenCli cli = new MavenCli(new ClassWorld("maven",Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()));
```

And then 2 subsequent doMain invocations of embedded maven succeed!

Comment: Maybe your code is for some reason not running inside a plexus Launcher, which sets the thread context class loader to the `ClassRealm` (at least back when I worked on this). Maybe something else between the launcher and your plugin is adding the different `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` as context class loader.